# Support https for embedded YouTube links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, youtube-embed

Https should be supported as well as http. Why? Because someone browsing YouTube via https will otherwise have to modify their link to remove the s. Every time.

Comment: Why do you want to be able to use https?

Comment: My downvote isn't for disagreement but because this is a terribly crafted question.

Comment: @InvaderSkoodge Sorry, better now?

Comment: @murgatroid99 [HTTPS everywhere is a thing that's happening with the kids these days](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).

Comment: @MarkTrapp That's the very reason I suggested this :-) HTTPS is all the rage these days...

Comment: Yep, being a semi-kid myself, I love HTTPS, not just for the heck of it, but for the safety that it provides too.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Agreed. Provided one does not light-heartedly click on the "permanently make an exception"-ish thing for self-signed certificates...

Comment: I forgot the mandatory security.SE link: [How does SSL work?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/3272)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will support https links to youtube after the next build.

Comment: Perfect, appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using accessing Arqade via https.  I made [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/175214/42984) which contains a video, but it does not show up on the https version of the Arqade page.